# Where to download GNU C++ compiler

Tags: c++, gnu

Can anyone suggest me where to download a GNU c++ compiler, which I can use in Ubuntu and also on Windows with Netbeans IDE, and also GNU tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any Linux/Unix/Solaris OS it is available unless you have explicitly not installed. That said, if you still wish to install GNU C++ compiler, use this command

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

and if you wish to download it on your windows, steps are [here](http://www.mingw.org/) on Minimalist GNU for Windows

Answer (score 10):

Getting everything you need on Debian/Ubuntu is very easy:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 6):

What about using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ?

Quoting it's homepage :

> The GNU Compiler Collection includes
>   front ends for C, C++, Objective-C,
>   Fortran, Java, and Ada, as well as
>   libraries for these languages
>   (libstdc++, libgcj,...).

It will definitly work on Ubuntu ; it's even provided through the package system *(sorry, my system is in french)* :

```
$ apt-cache show g++
Package: g++
...
Description-fr: Compilateur C++ du projet GNU
 Le compilateur C++ du projet GNU. Un compilateur C++ relativement portable
 et capable de bonnes optimisations.
```

(which translates to *Description: The GNU C++ compiler. This is the GNU C++ compiler, a fairly portable optimizing compiler for C++.* in English)

For informations about Windows support, you can have a look at : http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#windows

Something like [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) will probably do :-)

Quoting MinGW's homepage :

> MinGW, a contraction of "Minimalist
>   GNU for Windows", is a port of the GNU
>   Compiler Collection (GCC), and GNU
>   Binutils, for use in the development
>   of native Microsoft Windows
>   applications.

For netbeans, I can't tell : I don't use it -- not for C++, at least...

Comment: Just for the record: if you want the english messages just execute "LANG=en apt-cache show g++". Should work with pretty much all commands.

Comment: @Joachim : good to know! Thanks! (Didn't even know the english localization files were installed ^^ Well, I suppose they are by default ^^ )

Answer (score 5):

For windows, you will want [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Comment: Compilers under cygwin don't compile natively for Windows, they compile for the cygwin environment.  That's fine if that's what you want, but if you want to compile for Windows, you'll want mingw instead, as Gabe said.  MingW is a Windows port of GCC which can compile to Windows.

Comment: It still provides a gcc that can be used on windows with NetBeans; the overhead of adding cygwin.dll to any distribution is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo apt-get install g++` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://gcc.gnu.org/ and http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/gcc

Answer (score 0):

To install the gcc and g++ compilers, you will need the build-essential package. This will also install GNU make.

build-essential contains a list of packages which are essential for building Ubuntu packages including gcc compiler, make and other required tools.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ gcc -v
$ make -v
```

Now, you should able to compile software using C / C++ compilers.

To install the manpages for c and c++ development, install the manpages-dev package.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers